# VB.NET WinForms Date Time Picker change event runs twice?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datepicker, controls

I have the below code that runs when the user changes the date on my 'Ending' date DateTinePicker control:

```
Private Sub dtpEndDate_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dtpEndDate.ValueChanged
    If dtpEndDate.Value.Date < dtpStartDate.Value.Date Then
        MessageBox.Show("The end date should be after the start date", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        dtpEndDate.Value = Today
    End If
End Sub
```

This procedure seems to be running twice, in that the messagebox gets shown twice.

do I have the wrong event, or is there some better way of managing this?

I tried editing it with a variable as suggested:

```
Private Sub dtpEndDate_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dtpEndDate.ValueChanged

If m_blndtpEndDateIsDone = False Then
    If dtpEndDate.Value.Date < dtpStartDate.Value.Date Then
        MessageBox.Show("The end date should be after the start date", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        m_blndtpEndDateIsDone = True
        dtpEndDate.Value = Today
    Else
        m_blndtpEndDateIsDone = False
    End If
Else
    m_blndtpEndDateIsDone = False
End If
wnd sub
```

Unfortunately it is still firing twice...

I want it to fire once every time the end date dtpicker is modified and the date is before the start date.

thanks

Philip

Comment: why dtpEndDate.Value = Today?

Comment: well, it was really to cancel the changes...

Comment: This would show a `MessageBox` twice if `Today < dtpStartDate.Value.Date`. It may also fire multiple times if you're using both `AddHandler` and `Handles`.

Comment: @GLOIERTECH. yes, I have tried all the presented options, and now am trying the ErrorProvider option suggested by *@Hans Passant*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MessageBox can be quite troublesome like this.  It jerks the focus away from a control and pumps its own message loop.  That can cause *re-entrancy* problems, the kind that made DoEvents() so infamous.  The DateTimePicker control wasn't written to deal with this well, it is in general a balky kind of control.

A simple workaround is to avoid the in-your-face kind of error reporting.  The ErrorProvider component can do this nicely.  Drop one on your form and make your code look like this:

```
Private Sub dtpEndDate_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dtpEndDate.ValueChanged
    If dtpEndDate.Value.Date < dtpStartDate.Value.Date Then
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(dtpEndDate, "The end date should be after the start date")
        dtpEndDate.Value = Today
    Else
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(dtpEndDate, "")
    End If
End Sub
```

You actually can avoid the re-entrancy problem that MessageBox creates, you can do so by displaying it *later*, after the DateTimePicker has completed its own event processing.  Elegantly done in Winforms by using Control.BeginInvoke().  Make that look like this:

```
Private Sub dtpEndDate_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dtpEndDate.ValueChanged
    If dtpEndDate.Value.Date < dtpStartDate.Value.Date Then
        Me.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf reportDateProblem))
        dtpEndDate.Value = Today
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub reportDateProblem()
    MessageBox.Show("The end date should be after the start date", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Sub
```

Comment: well first, thanks for teaching me, however, although your first method does prevent the control showing a bad date, there is no message for the user as to why the control won't show the selected date- what am I missing?

Comment: You get an error icon, looks like a Stop traffic sign.  Hover the mouse over it to get the error message.  Very subtle.  If you prefer the in-your-face message then use the second solution I proposed.

Comment: I did add a dtpStartDate_ValueChanged event to also clear or show the error if the user chooses to set the StartDate picker incorrectly!

Answer (score 1):

this used to happen to me.

You can certify that you handle an event in two places at least in **WebForms**: in the asp page and in the code behind. If I have the syntax "Handles dtpEndDate.ValueChanged" after the signature of the "dtpEndDate_ValueChanged" method in the code behind as shown above then I don't have to write in my aspx "OnClick="dtpEndDate_ValueChanged"" or something like that.

While you're in **WinForms** and not in WebForms, Make sure you don't have

<<**AddHandler dtpEndDate.ValueChanged, AddressOf Me.dtpEndDate_ValueChanged**>>

or something like that somewhere in the Load method or elsewhere.

Hope it helps,

Yves

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use **dtpEndDate_Validating** event

```
Private Sub dtpEndDate_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs)
    If dtpEndDate.Value.[Date] < dtpStartDate.Value.[Date] Then
        MessageBox.Show("The end date should be after the start date", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
    End If
   e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

**or**

If you want to go with your event(dtpEndDate_ValueChanged) then define a boolean variable in the form and set the value to false. In your event after execution of first time message box set the variable to true. And check this variable

```
Dim isDone As Boolean = False

Private Sub dtpEndDate_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dtpEndDate.ValueChanged
If Not isDone Then
 If dtpEndDate.Value.Date < dtpStartDate.Value.Date Then
    MessageBox.Show("The end date should be after the start date", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    IsDone = True
    dtpEndDate.Value = Today
 End If
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: I'm stuck as now when I use the _validating_ event, it dowsn't seem to fire. The signaturee is **Private Sub dtpEndDate_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles dtpEndDate.Validating** but it won't fire even though I have a breakpoint.

Comment: yes that's right, but not what I want. I prefer to try and have it show an error when the data time picker for End date is before the date of the start date

Comment: Then go with second method given by me............Little bit changes in your code...

Comment: thanks for your help, but I like the ErroProvider solution proposed by Hans below!

Answer (score 1):

Try this out,

```
Private Sub dtpEndDate_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dtpEndDate.ValueChanged

     If (dtpEndDate.Value.Date < dtpStartDate.Value.Date) And Not dtpEndDate.Value = Today Then
            MessageBox.Show("The end date should be after the start date", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            dtpEndDate.Value = Today
     End If

 End Sub
```

you are resetting your date on `dtpEndDate` by `today's date`, so your `dtpStartDate` should be lesser than `today`, so there will be no logical clash will happen by using the above code.

Comment: I tried this code but it still runs twice, or shows the message box twice - possibly because I am changing the value to Today ?

Comment: thanks for your help, but I like the ErroProvider solution proposed by Hans below!